# Unable to resolve a component Resource Key

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having trouble resolving a component resource key in my WPF app for a DLL I was trying to use.

DLL source I'm trying to use:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

Error message:
The resource "{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type ScoreBoardClientTest:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}}" could not be resolved.

I've compiled the DLL and added it as a reference to my project.
I've added the appropriate xmlns filter to my XAML see below:

```
xmlns:filter="clr-namespace:DataGridFilterLibrary;assembly=DataGridFilterLibrary"
```

When I try to use a columnheaderstyle in my data grid is when the error above is thrown

```
ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
                               TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
                               ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
```

any help determining what I'm doing wrong here would be great. Thought it was straight forward.

Comment: Did you try to run the DataGridFilterTest application that is included in the downloadable .zip file? This should work. You could just copy ColumnHeaderStyle attribute from the Window1.xaml file into your XAML file. Make sure that you really have added a reference to the DataGridFilterLibrary project/assembly.

Comment: I ended up copying the entire project into mine and copying and pasting his code and it still failed with the same error. I'm at a complete loss. It doesn't make sense

Comment: Again, did you try to run the DataGridFilterTest application that is included in the downloadable .zip file? It certainly works as expected for me.

Comment: the download file works perfectly for me in the test application. but when I compile the DLL and add it to my own project is when I get this error. that is the problem I'm having. I'm curious what steps I would have to take to make sure this resolves. Do I have to do anything other then add the DLL as a reference, XMLNS filter to the XAML and the columnheaderstyles.   I have to be missing something but I haven't been able to figure it out. this is what I need assistance with. just understanding what I required to resolve the columnheaderstyle

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, when I using the filter in a UserControl. In a Window it works as expected.

Fixed this problem with adding the Ressource in the UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DataGridFilterLibrary;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```